# Can I substitute M for dM/dt in Kepler's equation?

Tags: calculus

The position of celestial bodies is given by orbital elements, one which is the mean anomaly, M. To get the position in xyz coordinates we first find the eccentric anomaly  by solving Kepler's equation $M = E-eSin(E)$ for the eccentric anomaly E, where e is the eccentricity. We then have that $x = aCos(E)$ and $y=bSin(E)$ where $a$ and $b$ are the semiaxes of the elliptic orbit.

Question: If I have $\frac{dM}{dt}$ can I go through the above procedure to yield $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$? I'm looking for arguments that will make it clear to me why or why not the substitution of $\frac{dM}{dt}$ in the place of $M$ is or isn't allowed.

EDIT: I intend to find $\frac{dE}{dt}$ by solving $\frac{dE_{i+1}}{dt}=\frac{E_i}{dt}+\frac{\frac{dM}{dt}+eSin(\frac{E_i}{dt})-\frac{E_i}{dt}}{1-eCos(\frac{E_i}{dt})}$ with $\frac{dE_0}{dt}=\frac{dM}{dt}$. Part of my question is whether this will still work. It is just the normal way of solving Kepler's equation with $\frac{dE}{dt}$ substituted for $E$ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have  $\frac {dx}{dt}=-a\frac {dE}{dt}\sin(E)$ Since $E$ is a transcendental function of $M$, it is not simple to assess $\frac {dE}{dt}$ from $\frac {dM}{dt}$.  You need $E$ as well.  For short intervals, you can expand $x$ and $y$ as Taylor series around the currently known position and be quite close.

Added:  Your usual way is Newton's method applied to Kepler's equation.  To do the same you would write $\frac {dM}{dt}=\frac {dE}{dt}(1-e\cos(E))$  No, you can't just substitute in $\frac {dE}{dt}$.  You can't take trig functions of that, as it has units of inverse time.  What you would have to do is write $\frac {dE}{dt}=\frac 1{1-e\cos(E)}\frac {dM}{dt}$ and then use Newton's method to find $\frac {dE}{dt}$  Probably better is to solve for $E(t)$ as you were doing, fit a polynomial to a few points, and take the derivative of that.

Comment: Thanks, you have answered my question. I'm being a bit thick at the moment though, could you tell me why I can't solve for E as I was doing and then plug E into the formula for $\frac{dE}{dt}$, that is, why would it be better to fit a polynomial and then take the derivative?

Comment: You certainly can solve for $E$ as you have been doing over a small unit of time, then approximating $\frac {dE}{dt}\approx \frac {\Delta E}{\Delta t}$.  The downside is that if $\Delta t$ is very short, errors in the values of $E$ translate into large errors in the derivative.  It is common to all numeric derivatives.  Polynomial fitting is a smoothing process, which reduces these errors.  But if things are accurate enough the other way, go for it.  You can play with various $\Delta t$ intervals to see what works best.